# How to make payable work with custom token

Tags: solidity

i have this function that actually works pretty well with native tokens.

I want it to withdraw the amount in the custom token i'm using. The Buy function i already managed to make it work but withdraw i'm stuck because of the payable part.

```
//Retirar Ganhos
function WithdrawWinnings() public isWinner {
    address payable winner = payable(msg.sender);
    uint256 reward2Transfer = winnings[winner];
    winnings[winner] = 0;
    winner.transfer(reward2Transfer);
}
```

I need to make it withdraw all the winnings using the token i created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Way to transfer native coin and ERC20 token is different. You can easily transfer native coin with `payable(winner).transfer(value)`. To transfer any ERC20 token you need to use `transfer` function of the token as below:

```
function WithdrawWinnings() public isWinner {
    address payable winner = payable(msg.sender);
    uint256 reward2Transfer = winnings[winner];
    winnings[winner] = 0;
    IER20(tokenContractAddress).transfer(winner, reward2Transfer);
}
```

Note: The winner address need not necessarily be a payable to transfer ERC20 token.

Answer (score 0):

function WithdrawWinnings() public isWinner {
address winner = msg.sender;
uint256 reward2Transfer = winnings[winner];
winnings[winner] = 0;

```
// The address of the custom token contract
address customTokenAddress = 0xcustom_token_address;

// The ABI (Application Binary Interface) of the custom token contract
bytes4 customTokenABI = 0xcustom_token_abi;

// Instantiate the custom token contract object
CustomToken customToken = CustomToken(customTokenAddress);

// Call the 'transfer' function on the custom token contract
customToken.transfer(winner, reward2Transfer);
```

}

you need to make sure that the contract that calls the withdraw function has enough balance of the token to do the transfer, otherwise the transaction will fail.

Comment: The contract that calls the withdraw function is the lottery Operator, the one that created the contract. It has enough funds on it.